# Je reconnais (de) nos affaires

Tags: grammaire

Dans *Féerie pour une autre fois* II :

> en plein milieu
> du carrelage ! cette pièce-là, celle-là, a trinqué ! pardon !... absolument comme notre « 5e » !... y a des choses d'ici, d'autres du dessus !... je reconnais **de** nos affaires à nous !...

Est-ce correct d'écrire *reconnaître **de** nos affaires* ? Je ne comprends pas très bien le sens du *de* ici.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il faut comprendre :

- Je reconnais (certaines/une partie/quelques unes) de nos affaires.

J'ai déjà entendu ce genre de choses, peut-être employé. Ça se dit et c'est compréhensible (pour un natif du moins), donc je ne vois pas pourquoi ce ne serait pas correct. Je ne vois rien d'incorrect à priori.

Autre contexte, même construction :

- Je reprendrais bien de ta tarte.
  On a tous compris que celui qui a dit ça voulait encore un morceau (dans ce cas) de ma tarte.

Comment: Cela se fait en tout cas entendre loin du monde germanopratin. Peut-être une résurgence du ou des patois [du Sud-Ouest en tout cas], surtout avec *de nos … à nous.*